# Dimension of a vector space-regarding

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the dimension of the vector space $V=\{u\in \mathbb{R}^3:Mu^{t}=u^{t}\}$, where $M=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&\cos \theta& -\sin \theta\\ 0& \sin \theta& \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}$, $0<\theta<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

I feel no vector $u$ except $(0,0,0)$ will satisfy this. Thus the dimension of $V$ is $0$. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you forgot the vector $(1,0,0)$. Notice that $M$ is a rotation of $\theta$ radians around the $x$-axis, thus that is the unique eigenvector (up to scalar multiples).